# How to control Cypress browser behaviour?

Tags: cypress

Hello everyone I'm facing an approach issue in my Cypress testing project. I'm making a navigation suite that logs in into the website and then goes througth the sidebar navigating the tabs. The issue here is that I each navigation as a test instead of just one big test so confused about the approach here.
At the begging I started this

```js
describe("Navigation Suite ", () => {

 beforeEach(() => {
        cy.viewport(1920, 900);
        cy.gotoWebsite();
        cy.loginWebsite();
    });

    it("should navigate to Clients", () => {
        cy.sideMenuCustomerServices("https://localhost/client");
    });

    it("should navigate to Records", () => {
        cy.sideMenuVatRegistration("https://localhost/records/client");
    });

    it("should navigate to Returns", () => {
        cy.sideMenuVatReturns("https://localhost/returns");
    });
```

Each *it* block will locate the navigation bar in the sidebar, click it, wait for the loading wheel to dissapear and check url.

And in this case the problem is that Cypress browser will reset after each test, so I disabled test isolation. That being said, that worked but only partially. If I rerun the test, user session won't be resseted even if I manually tell Cypress to in the before block.

```js
describe("Navigation Suite ", { testIsolation: false }, () => {

    before(() => {
        cy.clearCookies();
        cy.clearLocalStorage();
        cy.clearAllSessionStorage();
        cy.clearAllLocalStorage();
        cy.viewport(1920, 900);
        cy.gotoWebsite();
        cy.loginWebsite();
    })

   it("should navigate to Clients", () => {
        cy.sideMenuCustomerServices("https://localhost/client");
    });

    it("should navigate to Records", () => {
        cy.sideMenuVatRegistration("https://localhost/records/client");
    });

    it("should navigate to Returns", () => {
        cy.sideMenuVatReturns("https://localhost/returns");
    });
```

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn ***on*** test isolation, it's a good thing. It will help you avoid false-positive tests and make your tests more trustworthy.

To avoid the clear-down problems, just change the `before()` hook into a `beforeEach()` hook.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.viewport(1920, 900)
  cy.gotoWebsite()
  cy.loginWebsite()
})
```

You do not need to do all the clearing manually, Cypress already does it for you.

If you are concerned about repeating the login before every test will add to running time, use a `cy.session()` to cache the login steps

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.viewport(1920, 900)
  cy.session('login', () => {
    cy.gotoWebsite()
    cy.loginWebsite()
  })
})
```